# Parse error unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '('

Tags: wordpress

After upgrading to PHP 7.4, started getting

ParseError thrown
syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '('

when accessing posts, tags, categories

Everything went back to normal after deactivating CiviCRM 4.5 (I'm using Wordperfect version 5.6)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SE!  Do you really mean CiviCRM 4.5? - that's really old.  The docs Jitendra points to are for the current version of Civi.  If you are back on Civi 4.5 it won't work with any version of php7.

Go back to php5.6 and plan to upgrade.  You'll want to do that in stages - see some of the other answers on here for upgrading from very old versions.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php-version says it is still incompatible with PHP 7.4.

[image]

More info and discussion is at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1496